# Revise the number of ticks in the x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I only have a series of number, and I want to count the number of each element. Here is something I have done. X-axis is my element and Y-axis is the number of each element.

[image]

My question is, how could I revise the way of presentation in the x-axis? I only want to see 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8 and 0.9 in the axis, but still to keep the same number of bars in the figure (nothing changed). Any suggestion please?

```
d1 <- ggplot(TestData, aes(factor(TestData$Col1)))
d2 <- d1 + geom_bar() + xlab("") + ylab("")
```

Comment: Do you want a histogram or a bar chart?  If a histogram, use `Col1` as a continuous variable and `geom_histogram` and see if that helps.  Also, don't use dollar signs within `aes`, just refer to the variable directly.

Comment: + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0.4, 0.9, 0.1)) should do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create data with mean of 0.5, std of 0.2:

```
data<- rnorm(1000,0.5,0.2)
dataf <- data.frame(data)
```

Make histogram for all data range:

```
ggplot(aes(x = data),data = dataf) +
geom_histogram()
```

[image]

Xlim to 0.4 to 0.9:

```
ggplot(aes(x = data),data = dataf) +
geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0.4,0.9),
  breaks= scales::pretty_breaks(n=5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In base graphics, you can just omit the axes when generating the plot, then add them manually using the `axis` function:

```
set.seed(1234)
dat <- rnorm(1000, 0.5, 0.1)
hist(dat, axes = FALSE, xlim = c(0, 1))
axis(side = 2)
axis(side = 1, at = seq(0.4, 0.9, 0.1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how about using ggplot2? @dayne

Comment: I do everything in base R -- I much prefer it to ggplot. Why do you need ggplot here?

Comment: Thanks, same as you did using basic R, but achieve the same thing using ggplot? (If it does not bother you.)

Comment: I don't use ggplot -- someone else will have to add an answer if they feel like it. I would still argue you gain nothing by using ggplot in this example.